# How do I get FB.ui send method to work with multiple people?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

https://www.fbrell.com/saved/6ee3291eac888f0fee7d8a798e0c9210

There is an example of this working on fbrell and you can copy that to the official facebook test console at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ and it works great (if you replace the ID's with real ones).

However anytime I run this on my own domain it only populates the first user ID into the message send field. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: The [documentation for the Send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) describes the `to` parameter as follows: _“A user ID or username of a recipient.”_ – I think they are using _singular_ here for a reason. And it goes on, _“Once the dialog comes up, the sender can specify additional people, groups, and email addresses as recipients.”_

Comment: Why that works on FBRell I can’t tell you – but from the additional info box further up on the doc page I think it is pretty clear that it is not intended that you put multiple user ids in there. Let the user himself decide if he wants to add additional users as receivers for the message – pre-filling to with a larger number of user ids would be quite spammy anyway.

Comment: That's what I figured, I was just confused as to why it was working on FBRell but not on my own. Thanks